# Find difference of product of binary vector to binary matrix after fliping one bit in the vector.

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, sparse-matrices

We have: $E1=x*W*x^{T}\\
Delta = E1 - x_{new} * W * x_{new}^{T}$
where $x_{new}$ is the $x$ vector with 1 bit flipped from 1 to -1 or the other way. Is there a way to find $Delta$ without having to recalculate the matrix multiplications? All the values in $W$ and $x$ are either 1 or -1 and the diagonal of $W$ is zero.

Comment: Is $W$ symmetric? If not, I suppose you could replace it with $(W + W^T)/2$ before starting...  (I wondered because you included the tag "symmetric matrices".)

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes its symmetric sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $W$ symmetic:

Let $x$ and $y$ denote the vectors you've called $x$ and $x_{new}$. Let $u$ denote $x - y$, which is all zeros except a single $\pm 2$ in some location $j$. Use primes to denote transposes.

$$
u' A u = x'Ax - 2x' A y + y' A y
$$
The left hand side is just $4 \cdot a_{jj}$. The first term on the RHS is known. Let's continue
$$
u' A u 
= x'Ax - 2x' A y + y' A y\\
u'Au - x'Ax + 2x' A y = y' A y\\
u'Au + x'Ax - 2x'Ax + 2x' A y = y' A y\\
u'Au + x'Ax + 2x'A(y-2x) = y' A y
$$
The first term is easy, as noted; the second is known. Half the third is 
$$
x' A (y - 2x) = x'A (u-x) = x'Au - x'Ax
$$
so we can write
$$
u'Au + x'Ax + 2x'A(y-2x) = y' A y\\
u'Au + x'Ax + 2x'Au - 2x'A'x = y' A y\\
u'Au - x'Ax + 2x'Au = y' A y\\
$$
Now the third term is $2x'$ times the product of $A$ with $\pm 2 e_j$, i.e., it's just $\pm 4 x' c$, where $c$ is the $j$th column of $A$.

For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, this saves you a factor of $n$ in computation.

(I'm sure there's a simpler algebraic way to get here, but I leave that to you.)